TV serial from the 80s or 90s with a magic lantern
I've been trying forever to identify a show that I watched in 1997 or '98. I believe it was a US-made television serial, and I think the running theme was that someone had a "magic lantern" (a type of film projector) on their attic, but it was literally magical in the sense that it allowed the viewer to enter the scene that was being projected.
In the episode I recall, two younger people found the lantern along with some civil war footage, visited the scene of the film, and then there was some danger of them getting back because (I think) the lantern was driven by a real candle and it was either about to run out or someone was going to blow it out, or maybe they had to blow it out in order to prevent something bad from escaping the film into the real world.
I imagine it would have been a contemporary or at least recent show (90s), but it could have been a bit older.
Does any of this sound at all familiar?

Sounds like the Friday the 13th season 2 episode Eye of Death from 1989.

A devious antiques dealer uses a magic lantern to travel back to the Civil War so he can steal artifacts from dead soldiers.

Protagonist Ryan gets stuck in the past after chasing the villain and a young widow assists him there. Here's the promo:



